# Successor of iterator is not necessarily a regular function: how is it possible?

Tags: c++, iterator, regular-type

In page 91 of the book *Elements of Programming*, Stepanov and McJones say that the concept of Iterator requires a `successor` function but that is *not necessarily* regular because

> ...`i = j` does not imply that `successor(i) = successor(j)`...

(see [page online](https://books.google.com/books?id=tjOlkl7ecVQC&lpg=PA91&ots=12JoXbD85G&dq=iterator%20successor%20not%20regular&pg=PA91#v=onepage&q&f=false))

I understand the converse `successor(i) = successor(j)` does not imply `i=j` (for example in two null terminated list) and that `successor` function may not be defined for some inputs. But I don't understand how could it be possible that `i = j` can lead to `successor(i) != successor(j)`.

**What case would they be referring to?** Perhaps some iterator that does random (as in aleatory) hops? or some iterator that has a hidden state and "jumps" differently than the other iterator after pointing to the same element (and comparing equal in this sense).

They immediately jump to refinements (ForwardIterator) that require a regular `successor` function so it is not clear to me.

---

Initially I thought that an input iterator can have this property. However is still difficult to me to see if this constitutes a counterexample: (within a certain implementation of STL).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <cassert>
using std::cout; using std::endl;
int main(){
    std::istream_iterator<int> it1(std::cin); // wait for one input
    std::istream_iterator<int> it2 = it1;
    assert(it1 == it2);
    cout << "*it1 = " << *it1 << endl;
    cout << "*it2 = " << *it2 << endl;
    cout << "now sucessor" << endl;
    ++it1; // wait for one input
    ++it2; // wait for another input
    assert(it1 == it2); // inputs still compare equal !
    cout << "*it1 = " << *it1 << endl;
    cout << "*it2 = " << *it2 << endl;
    assert(it1 == it2); // also here ! and yet they point to different values...
    assert(*it1 == *it2); // assert fails! 
}
```

(compiled with GCC 6.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example could be a *successor* function that consumes a stream of data (as they mention in the book).
When you have read the *i-th* element, you can theoretically invoke the *successor* function for it only once. If you try to invoke it twice, the results are different.
Simply imagine that `successor(i)` reads the next element from the stream, that is the *i-th+1* element. It actually means to consume it and it won't be available anymore. If you call `successor(i)` another time, you will get the *i-th+2* element from the stream.
Thus, if the inputs are the same (`i = j`), you have no guarantees that the outputs are the same (`successor(i) = successor(j)`).

Comment: yes, makes sense but when I want to *implement* a counter example the input (istream) iterators still compare equal. Even more confusing is that `*it1 != *it2`, maybe it is an implementation problem. (see the new code in my equation). I know I shouldn't compare the axiomatic book of Stepanov with a mundane implementation of STL, but I wonder if in practice the ideals still hold in a practice.

Comment: ok, I am doing more test and `it1 == it2` no matter the order of the operators. It looks like in the implementation I have the two iterators will keep being equal as long as they were assigned at some point.

Comment: In context, this example looks more like a non-regular `source` function (`*`).

Comment: @alfC You know that I got the example from the book you are reading, right? This is the example they use to explain what you asked.

Comment: Well, yes, but when I tried to implement an example with input iterators from STL where this is the case, I wasn't able to. True, it could be that a real STL input iterator is not a faithful representation of that case, but how else one know show an input iterator is supposed to behave or compare equal. The only thing I was able to actually prove is that `source` is not a regular function on input iterators.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the type `iter` defined as:

```
struct iter { unsigned value; };

inline bool operator==(iter const& x, iter const& y) {
  return x.value == y.value;
}
inline bool operator!=(iter const& x, iter const& y) {
  return !(x == y);
}
auto source(iter const& x) {
  return x.value;
}
iter successor(iter const&) {
  std::random_device engine{};
  std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned> dist{};
  return {dist(engine)};
}
```

IIRC, `iter` satisfies the requirements for EoP's `Iterator` concept: it is `Regular`, `source` is a regular function, `successor` notably is *not* regular.
Given two objects `i` and `j` of type `iter` such that `i == j`, it is extremely likely that `successor(i) != successor(j)`.

Comment: Yes, this is the example I had in mind. But it looked pretty convolved and didn't know if that is what they had in mind or if there was an application for that. I guess one can imagine an iterator that randomly covers a sequence (repeating or not repeating elements).